# Monitoring changes in collaborators on github

Tags: github, github-api, github-archive

I have a pet project where I am trying to get some stats about collaborators (core team members, as per https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Contributors-vs-Collaborators). Basically I want to know when people were added to a repo. Since I want to get that info retroactively, I was thinking of using the github archive.

According to the docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#memberevent) MemberEvent is what I am looking for. Yet, as far as I can tell, there are barely any events of that sort in the Github Archive. All I find are 'added' events. Is there somewhere on a repo's page where I should be able to see it so that I can triangulate what i retrieve from github archive and the project page?

Thanks a lot!